# Installing Busser plugins: busser-serverspec never finishes (OSX, Virtualbox)

Tags: macos, vagrant, chef-infra, test-kitchen, serverspec

When I run `kitchen test` on my MacBook, it gets through most of the steps, but then gets stuck here twiddling its thumbs:

```
       Running handlers:
       Running handlers complete
       Chef Client finished, 81/117 resources updated in 07 minutes 12 seconds
       Finished converging <default-ubuntu-1404> (7m42.70s).
-----> Setting up <default-ubuntu-1404>...
       Finished setting up <default-ubuntu-1404> (0m0.00s).
-----> Verifying <default-ubuntu-1404>...
       Preparing files for transfer
-----> Installing Busser (busser)
Fetching: thor-0.19.0.gem (100%)
       Successfully installed thor-0.19.0
Fetching: busser-0.7.1.gem (100%)
       Successfully installed busser-0.7.1
       2 gems installed
       Installing Busser plugins: busser-serverspec
```

Several hours later, still says the same thing. No progress. Oddly, it never errors or times out, either - just keeps waiting for something. And it doesn't happen on my work MacBook, only my home one (late 2011 - old, but still effective).

Mac OS 10.11.4 (El Capitan), ChefDK 0.13.21, Virtualbox 5.0.20, Kitchen.yml:

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04

suites:
  - name: default
    data_bags_path: "test/integration/data_bags" 
    run_list:
      - recipe[devserver::default]
    attributes:
```

Any ideas? Ways I can dig deeper and debug? Solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Nuke the Vagrant box and let it redownload from Bento, you might have an old version with some wonky Ruby settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly it's still running forever :'(

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I copied bits of the recipe one-by-one to a new cookbook and figured it out. The problem was a conflict between the [users cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/users), the [sudo cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo), and Vagrant.

tl;dr the sudo cookbook strips the "vagrant" user of its power. I imagine busser was stuck waiting to enter a password or something. To fix, I added the following to my `.kitchen.yml` :

```
suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[mycookbook::default]
    data_bags_path: "test/integration/data_bags" 
    attributes:
      authorization:
        sudo:
          passwordless: true
          users: ['vagrant']
```

This lets the vagrant user run sudo commands without a password, and busser can once again install its plugins.

If my google-fu had been a little better, I might have found [someone else who had a similar problem](http://clarkdave.net/2013/02/vagrant-chef-and-the-sudo-cookbook/). Hopefully another copy of the issue + answer on the internet will make it easier for someone else to figure out.

Comment: Since this is the solution to your problem, I'd suggest accepting your answer so that it's marked as solved.